# SQL - how to query to find if two columes are 1to1 1tomany manytomany relationship?

Tags: sql, sql-server, relationship

I want to draw a class diagram to describe the relationship between columes. how to query to find if two columes are 1to1 or 1tomany or manytomany relationship? for example, below table shows that column "name" is 1-to-many with colume "prod".

[image]

Comment: You don't look at data for table relationship.  You look at the table structure.

Comment: Is there really a relationship or is it just implied? Many times I have seen databases where there is not an explicit relationship between tables and the application implies one.

Comment: hello, I am looking at relationship between columns, not between tables. I just want to know, for example,  if records in column A is 1-to-1 with records in column B. Please dont make it complicated.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question? Are you inquiring about a `JOIN` maybe? Is this homework? Is there any visuals or additional details you can provide us?

Comment: If you're looking for relationship between columns in a table, then your table structure are so messed up.

Comment: hello all, please see the example. I have 3M+ records and it's impossible for me to identify the relationships between any of the two columns via the naked eyes.

Comment: The problem is no one understand what you want.  Please provide table structure, sample input, sample output.  Here's a good reference of how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hello Eric, example is provided. Please take a look and advise if possible. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any record returned would mean a 1 to many

```
select A
from table
group by A,B
having count(*) >1
```

Comment: Thanks for your demonstration. But I find this method not working well. such as below simple example                                                                      name prod
a 1
a 2
b 1
c 2
d 2
e 3
f 1
g 2
h 1
select name from test.relationship
group by name, prod
having count(*) > 1

Answer (score 0):

I found below query works. It will show me any records in 1st column (i.e.name) which have more than one values in the 2nd column (i.e.prod), and vice versa which together could show if the two columns are 1:1 or 1:many or many：1 or many:many

```
    select name, count(prod) 
from (select name, prod from test.relationship
      group by name, prod) subtable
group by name
having count(prod) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The difficult part is detecting the many-many relationship which is similar to a circuit.  You need to find, for any column pair, if the value on either side has another pairing.  For the 1-many or many-1 it's more straightforward, just count matches by row in an outer apply(). This looks a little daunting, but seems to do the trick...

```
    create table #relationships (col_a char(1), col_b int)

-- one to one
insert into #relationships select 'a', 1

-- one to many
insert into #relationships select 'b', 2
insert into #relationships select 'b', 3

-- many to many
insert into #relationships select 'c', 4
insert into #relationships select 'c', 5
insert into #relationships select 'd', 5

-- many to one
insert into #relationships select 'e', 6
insert into #relationships select 'f', 6


select  a.col_a,
        a.col_b,
        case when circuit.col_a is not null then 'Many-Many' -- order important 
             when cnt1.cnt1 = 1 and cnt2.cnt2 = 1 then 'One-One'
             when cnt1.cnt1 = 2 and cnt2.cnt2 = 1 then 'One-Many'
             when cnt1.cnt1 = 1 and cnt2.cnt2 = 2 then 'Many-One'
        end
from #relationships a
cross apply( select count(*) cnt1
             from ( select distinct col_b
                    from #relationships b
                    where b.col_a = a.col_a )x) cnt1
cross apply( select count(*) cnt2
             from ( select distinct col_a
                    from #relationships b
                    where b.col_b = a.col_b )x) cnt2

left join ( select x.col_a,
                   x.col_b 
            from #relationships a
            outer  apply ( select b.col_a,
                                  b.col_b
                           from #relationships b
                            where  a.col_a = b.col_a
                                    and exists ( select 1
                                                 from #relationships c
                                                 where b.col_b = c.col_b
                                                   and c.col_a <> a.col_a ) 
                              and ( a.col_b = b.col_b
                                    and exists ( select 1
                                                 from #relationships c
                                                 where b.col_a = c.col_a
                                                   and c.col_b <> a.col_b ))) x 
        ) circuit
    on a.col_a = circuit.col_a 
    or  a.col_b = circuit.col_b 

col_a col_b       
----- ----------- ---------
a     1           One-One
b     2           One-Many
b     3           One-Many
c     4           Many-Many
c     5           Many-Many
d     5           Many-Many
e     6           Many-One
f     6           Many-One
```